# How to create a new panel with radio buttons depending on menu item selected

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a gui that when I select an item from the menuBar it creates a sort of form with radio buttons in the empty field below. I want the items in that field to change depending on what option is selected. How can I do this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Fireurza
 */
public class RSSGUIMenuBar extends JFrame implements MenuListener, KeyListener,  ActionListener
{
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu shop, partOption, modelOption, orderOption, customerOption, employeeOption, reportOption, exit;
    JMenuItem searchParts, browseParts, editParts, newParts;
    JMenuItem searchModels, browseModels, editModels, newModels;
    JMenuItem searchOrders, browseOrders, editOrders, newOrders;
    JMenuItem searchCustomers, browseCustomers, editCustomer, newCustomer;
    JMenuItem searchEmployees, browseEmployees, editEmployee, newEmployee;
    JMenuItem openReport, searchReport;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RSSGUIMenuBar fr = new RSSGUIMenuBar();
        fr.setVisible(true);             
    }

    public RSSGUIMenuBar()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(900,700);
        setTitle("Robbie Robot Shop");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // listens when key pressed
        this.addKeyListener(this);

        // Create menu bar
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //build the first heading on menu bar
        shop = new JMenu("Shop");
      // shop.addMenuListener(new thisMenuListener());
        menuBar.add(shop);

        // creat exit menu item
        exit = new JMenu("Exit");
        exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        exit.addMenuListener(this);
        menuBar.add(exit);

        //sub menu partOption
        partOption = new JMenu("Parts");
        //partOption.addMenuListener(new thisMenuListener());
        shop.add(partOption);

        // sub menus of Parts
        searchParts = new JMenuItem("Search Parts");
        browseParts = new JMenuItem("Browse Parts");
        editParts = new JMenuItem("Edit Part");
        newParts = new JMenuItem("New Part");
                     //new JMenuItem("SearchParts", new ImageIcon("images/image.gif));
        searchParts.addActionListener(this);
        browseParts.addActionListener(this);
        editParts.addActionListener(this);
        newParts.addActionListener(this);
        partOption.add(searchParts);
        partOption.add(browseParts);
        partOption.add(editParts);
        partOption.add(newParts);


        // sub menu modelOption
        modelOption = new JMenu("Models");
      //  modelOption.addMenuListener(new thisMenuListener());
        shop.add(modelOption);

        // sub menus of Models
        searchModels = new JMenuItem("Search Models");
        browseModels = new JMenuItem("Browse Models");
        editModels = new JMenuItem("Edit Model");
        newModels = new JMenuItem("New Model");
                     //new JMenuItem("SearchModels", new ImageIcon("images/image.gif));
        searchModels.addActionListener(this);
        browseModels.addActionListener(this);
        editModels.addActionListener(this);
        newModels.addActionListener(this);
        modelOption.add(searchModels);
        modelOption.add(browseModels);
        modelOption.add(editModels);
        modelOption.add(newModels);

        // sub menu orderOption
        orderOption = new JMenu("Orders");
      //  orderOption.addMenuListener(new thisMenuListener());
        shop.add(orderOption);

        // sub menus of Orders
        searchOrders = new JMenuItem("Search Orders");
        browseOrders = new JMenuItem("Browse Orders");
        editOrders = new JMenuItem("Edit Order");
        newOrders = new JMenuItem("New Order");
                     //new JMenuItem("Search Orders", new ImageIcon("images/image.gif));
        searchOrders.addActionListener(this);
        browseOrders.addActionListener(this);
        editOrders.addActionListener(this);
        newOrders.addActionListener(this);
        orderOption.add(searchOrders);
        orderOption.add(browseOrders);
        orderOption.add(editOrders);
        orderOption.add(newOrders);

        //sub menu customerOption
        customerOption = new JMenu("Customers");
      //  customerOption.addMenuListener(new thisMenuListener());
        shop.add(customerOption);

        // sub menus of Customers
        searchCustomers = new JMenuItem("Search Customers");
        browseCustomers = new JMenuItem("Browse Customers");
        editCustomer = new JMenuItem("Edit Customer");
        newCustomer = new JMenuItem("New Customer");
                     //new JMenuItem("Search Customers", new ImageIcon("images/image.gif));
        searchCustomers.addActionListener(this);
        browseCustomers.addActionListener(this);
        editCustomer.addActionListener(this);
        newCustomer.addActionListener(this);
        customerOption.add(searchCustomers);
        customerOption.add(browseCustomers);
        customerOption.add(editCustomer);
        customerOption.add(newCustomer);

        // sub menu employeeOption
        employeeOption = new JMenu("Employees");
      //  employeeOption.addMenuListener(new thisMenuListener());
        shop.add(employeeOption);

        // sub menus of Employees
        searchEmployees = new JMenuItem("Search Employees");
        browseEmployees = new JMenuItem("Browse Employees");
        editEmployee = new JMenuItem("Edit Employee");
        newEmployee = new JMenuItem("New Employee");
                     //new JMenuItem("Search Employees", new ImageIcon("images/image.gif));
        searchEmployees.addActionListener(this);
        browseEmployees.addActionListener(this);
        editEmployee.addActionListener(this);
        newEmployee.addActionListener(this);
        employeeOption.add(searchEmployees);
        employeeOption.add(browseEmployees);
        employeeOption.add(editEmployee);
        employeeOption.add(newEmployee);

        // sub menu reportOption
        reportOption = new JMenu("Reports");
      //  reportOption.addMenuListener(new thisMenuListener());
        shop.add(reportOption);

        // sub menus of Reports
        searchReport = new JMenuItem("Search Reports");
        openReport = new JMenuItem("Open Report");
                     //new JMenuItem("Search Reports", new ImageIcon("images/image.gif));
        searchReport.addActionListener(this);
        openReport.addActionListener(this);
        reportOption.add(searchReport);
        reportOption.add(openReport);

        // add menu bar to frame
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    }
    // needed for implements
    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent me)
    {
        if (me.getSource().equals(exit))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent me)
    {
        //not used but must exist
    }

    @Override
    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent me)
    {
        //not used but must exist
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        //not used but must exist
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        if(ke.getKeyChar() == 'x')
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        //not used but must exist
    }

    // These are the action listeners
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // search parts
        if(e.getSource().equals(searchParts))
        {

        }
        // browse parts
        if(e.getSource().equals(browseParts))
        {

        }
        // edit parts
        if(e.getSource().equals(editParts))
        {

        }
        // new parts
        if(e.getSource().equals(newParts))
        {

        }
        // search model
        if(e.getSource().equals(searchModels))
        {

        }
        // browse model
        if(e.getSource().equals(browseModels))
        {

        }
        // edit model
        if(e.getSource().equals(editModels))
        {

        }
        // new model
        if(e.getSource().equals(newModels))
        {

        }
        // search order
        if(e.getSource().equals(searchOrders))
        {

        }
        // browse order
        if(e.getSource().equals(browseOrders))
        {

        }
        // edit order
        if(e.getSource().equals(editOrders))
        {

        }
        // new order
        if(e.getSource().equals(newOrders))
        {

        }
        // search customer
        if(e.getSource().equals(searchCustomers))
        {

        }
        // browse customer
        if(e.getSource().equals(browseCustomers))
        {

        }
        // edit customer
        if(e.getSource().equals(editCustomer))
        {

        }
        // new customer
        if(e.getSource().equals(newCustomer))
        {

        }
        // search employee
        if(e.getSource().equals(searchEmployees))
        {

        }
        // browse employee
        if(e.getSource().equals(browseEmployees))
        {

        }
        // edit employee
        if(e.getSource().equals(editEmployee))
        {

        }
        // new employee
        if(e.getSource().equals(newEmployee))
        {

        }
        // open report
        if(e.getSource().equals(openReport))
        {

        }
        // search report
        if(e.getSource().equals(searchReport))
        {

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: My "gut" feeling is, the forms are (relatively) static in nature, to create one or more custom class which contain the information you want to present. You might even be able to pass that information you want displayed to this class and have the class generate the contents if that works for you. I'd then use a `CardLayout` to switch between them

Comment: The forms for newPart is very different for the forms for newOrder.

Comment: Then it suggests you need separate classes